# Canvas appearing above the frame placed at the top

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I have used the top template from this website and not changed much:

This is Start Page which should be displayed when the program is started

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        def check_user_login():
            #removed code it just updates items on canvas based on entry inputs

            if un == True and pw == True:
                print("Login verified")
                app().show_frame("PageOne") # This line does not work need a way to show other frames without using a button
                return None

        #create a canvas to place images on
        canvas = Canvas(self.controller, bg = "#5c5c5c",height = 400,width = 800,bd = 0,highlightthickness = 0,relief = "flat")
        canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)

#removed code here to free up space

        #top text box
        un_img = PhotoImage(file = f"img_textBox0.png")
        un_bg = canvas.create_image(400.0, 200.0, image=un_img, tags="username_box")
        un_input = Entry(bd = 0, bg = "#5c5c5c")
        un_input.place(x = 310.0, y = 189,width = 180.0,height = 21)

        #background image
        background_img = PhotoImage(file = f"background.png")
        background = canvas.create_image(371.5, 185.5, image=background_img)

        #login button
        login_button_img = PhotoImage(file = f"img0.png")
        b0 = Button(image = login_button_img, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0, command = check_user_login, relief = "flat")
        b0.place(x = 356, y = 290,width = 89,height = 29)

        #figure out what this does and why it's important
        self.background_img = background_img
        self.un_img = un_img
        self.login_button_img = login_button_img
        self.ip_red = ip_red
```

But even though the program should move StartPage to the top of the window only the canvas from the frame below are visible, if I remove the canvas from PageOne (below) the contents of StartPage is visible again.

```py
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
```

I am unsure what is going wrong or how to go about fixing it

Comment: The so-called "top template" you're referring to requires that all page `Frames` be the same size — I can't tell if that is true for what you're doing or not. You may need to post a [mre] to get help on this problem.

Comment: You aren't explicitly specifying the parent for at least some of your widgets.  Without a defined hierarchy to work with, you aren't going to be able to lay them out nicely.

Answer (score 0):

This part is wrong:

```
canvas = Canvas(self.controller, ...)
```

Everything created in a page needs to be a child of that page or a descendant of the page. `self.controller` needs to be `self`

```
canvas = Canvas(self, ...)
```

The other widgets are also wrong, because you don't specify a master at all:

```
un_input = Entry(bd = 0, bg = "#5c5c5c")
...
b0 = Button(image = login_button_img, ...)
```

Both need to have `self` as the first parameter:

```
un_input = Entry(self, bd = 0, bg = "#5c5c5c")
...
b0 = Button(self, image = login_button_img, ...)
```

Comment: I just changed self.comment to self and now nothing is being placed in the frame, which shows I've been placing things in the wrong place to start with but now nothing showing up with self

Comment: @WillJordan: I don't know what you mean by `changed self.comment`. However, it sounds like you're not making the page visible.

Comment: Well you said the items placed need to be a child of the page and use self which I have now done and now nothing is showing up.  Inside the parent frame there is a function that I think moves the chosen frame to the top and that is what made the page visible which isn't happening.  The help is really appreciated, thank you very much